# Running external unix commands in Scala

Tags: scala, unix, apache-spark

Trying to run some external commands through a scala code.

This is a line from it

```
import sys.process._
("hdfs dfs -cat /data/test/zipfiletest/filename")!
```

Here instead of directly  specifying the filename I have this filename in a scala variable.
How do I append this filename to the existing command.

Tried something like :

```
("hdfs dfs -cat /data/test/zipfiletest/")+filename!
```

But this doesn't work.
Is there another way to do it?

Comment: How about just using string interpolation?
`(s"hdfs dfs -cat /data/test/zipfiletest/$filename")!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this  :

```
import sys.process._
(s"hdfs dfs -cat /data/test/zipfiletest/$filename")!
```

Comment: When I run a spark-job in cluster mode containing this cat command I get an error of : `I/O error Pipe closed for process: [hdfs, dfs, -cat, /data/test/filename.pgp]`. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: @Rohan Oswal Well the command will be executed on either the driver or any worker according to the whole code. But the way I'll do it is : I would read the file using hadoop api in the Spark job and [broadcast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) the content of the file in your spark cluster so that it will be available to any worker. But I don't really know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

you can use string interpolation or string concatenation

string interpolation:

```
import sys.process._
(s"hdfs dfs -cat /data/test/zipfiletest/$filenameVariable")!
```

string concatenation:

```
import sys.process._
("hdfs dfs -cat /data/test/zipfiletest/" + filename)!
```

personally I would go for the string interpolation, is more readable

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation e.g.

```
s"hdfs dfs -cat $myVariable"
```

but beware if your filename contains a space! For that reason you may prefer to invoke the Unix command using an API call taking each argument separately (rather than letting the API parse out each argument separately - which will fail in the above scenario)